# Concurrent.futures: what are the use cases for map() vs. submit()?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-3.x

I am going through the Python concurrent.futures module and using it to become more familiar with parallel/concurrent programming models. Unfortunately, since it is a relatively new module, I cannot find a significant amount of beginner-oriented literature.

I understand that map() returns the direct return value of a function called on the iterable through the processes or threads. And submit() returns a futures object.

I would like more explanation of why one might choose to use one or the other. It seems like map() is more for clearly parallel tasks that do not need to be coordinated. And submit() might be more useful for complex concurrent use cases. However, I am pretty new to this, and was hoping that someone more knowledgeable could expand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`map` is used to call a single function on one or more iterables. `submit` is used to generate a `Future` object for a single function call with its associated arguments.

Think of `concurrent.map` as just a parallel version of the builtin `map` function. `submit` is used to generate a future.